# Report generation by changing content data to title field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

hello we have a small project for making reservations of our assets.
we are holding it as following table 1.
we want to have query result like table 2 for pretty printing 
but I couldnt manage to do it,
if you have previously solve similar issues, can you help me like which subjects should I search
in oracle database or PLSQL?

```
existing
TABLE 1
ASSET_NAME, USER_ID,  RESERVATION_PERIOD 
PS1, 41 , AM
PS1, 1  , PM
PS2, -  , - 
PS3, -  , - 
PS4, -  , - 

new table
TABLE 2
ASSET_NAME, AM,  PM
PS1, 41 , 1
PS2, -  , - 
PS3, (user_id)  , (user_id if it is allocated)
PS4, -  , -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple select should work. Read #CASE #ANALYTICS #CONNECT BY etc. Note: the below will have 2 rows for PS1, this SQL has to be modified using CONNECT BY clause

```
INSERT INTO
      TABLE2 ( ASSET_NAME,
             AM,
             PM )
    ( SELECT
           ASSET_NAME,
           CASE
               WHEN USER_ID IS NOT NULL
                   AND RESERVATION_PERIOD = 'AM'
               THEN
                   USER_ID
               ELSE
                   NULL
           END
               AS AM,
           CASE
               WHEN USER_ID IS NOT NULL
                   AND RESERVATION_PERIOD = 'PM'
               THEN
                   USER_ID
               ELSE
                   NULL
           END
               AS PM
     FROM
           TABLE1 );
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer i have tried the query but it is generating the result as 
<p>ASSET_NAME AM PM
<p>PS1 41  - 
<p>PS1  -  1
<p>PS2  -  - 
<p>PS3  -  - 
<p>PS4  -  -
 but our goal is to collect all single asset data in single row like <p>ASSET_NAME, AM,  PM
<p>PS1, 41 , 1
<p>PS2, -  , - 
<p> how can i compress 2 s1 to a single row?

Comment: yes.. make this as a subquery and use CONNECT BY clause to get your results

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  asset_name
,       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN reservation_period = 'AM' THEN user_id ELSE NULL END), '-') AS am_user_id
,       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN reservation_period = 'PM' THEN user_id ELSE NULL END), '-') AS pm_user_id
FROM    table_1
GROUP   BY
        asset_name;
```